# How to debug one file and not the package in Rust?

Tags: debugging, rust

I'm learning Rust, and I'm using VSCode with extensions: `rust-analyzer`, `codeLLDB`, and `Code Runner`. On Manjaro.

I've created a project (package?) by using `cargo` with the following structure:

```
the_rust_programming_language
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── ch01
│   │   └── hello_world.rs
│   ├── ch02
│   │   └── guessing_game.rs
│   ├── ch03
│   ├── ch04
│   └── main.rs
└── target
    ├── CACHEDIR.TAG
    ├── debug
    └── rls
```

Using `code runner` extension I can run every RS-type file without any problems. Now I'm trying to debug every file individually but the debugger only recognize `main.rs` and it tries debug that file only.

This is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug executable 'the_rust_programming_language'",
      "cargo": {
        "args": [
          "build",
          "--bin=the_rust_programming_language",
          "--package=the_rust_programming_language"
        ],
        "filter": {
          "name": "the_rust_programming_language",
          "kind": "bin"
        }
      },
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    },
  ]
}
```

So, how should I debug one only file?

I have this another little problem: recently I changed my etension from `rust` to `rust-analyzer` and in my editor (for some files) I get this warning `file not included in module tree`. What does it mean? How to fix it?

Comment: HS: I have almost zero experience using debug tool like this, I would advice you to use crate lib `tracing` or `log` that will add a real plus to your code allowing to improve all your futures debug contrary to invest time using debugger where the time used to debug is loose forever.

Comment: Not sure how exactly do you want to debug only one file. `main.rs` is an entry point, so, if you launch your program for debugging, it will be loaded anyway.

Comment: Then how should I debug, for example, `hello_world.rs` only? Do I need put it in a new project?

Comment: Sure, each application is an individual project.